# Установка в PDO констант по умолчанию

Tags: php, pdo

Для вывода результата из запроса нужно установить

```
PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
```

Можно ли данную константу установить по умолчанию при подключении к БД для вывода данных в виде только ассоциативного массива?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно. Для этого после подключения вызовите вот такой `setAttribute`:

```
$connection = new PDO($connection_string); 
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Да, точно.. Совсем забыл про setAttribute) Спасибо большое)

Comment: можно сразу в конструктор писать опции массивом без `setAttribute`